# How to share common classes with extension with many dependencies in a smooth way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im currently working on a iOS project where we now want to add some feature for the Apple Watch. Since the extension for Apple Watch is a different target I naturally can't access the code written for the App. I have searched here on stackoverflow and have found two different ways to solve this problem.

1. Create a dynamic frameworks. This would definitely be the best approach but unfortunately the app must support down to iOS 6, and what I have found this solution will only work on iOS 8+.
2. Link the files in either Build Phases -> Compile Sources or through Target Membership in File Inspector. The main problem here is that the two classes we want to use have many dependencies to many other classes, which also have other dependencies and so on. From what I understand I need to include all these other files as well if I want to make use of the classes I intend to use in the extension.

So my question is if there is any other better way for me to accomplish this. If I choose #2, first of all I need to include all files, and after that, from a maintenance point of view, if I make changes to there files, for example importing an other class, I need to include that one as well in Compile Sources / Target Membership. Would really appreciate any ideas or advice regarding this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how "deep" is your coupling regarding point 2. However if you can use interfaces(protocols) instead of direct class referencing you can separate just the classes you need.

Moreover you could re-think whether specific class really need some other class to operate(probably not) or just some methods from it. Those methods could be moved to protocol and your dependant class to implement it(now this class do not need to be part of AppWatch target).

This will be heavy work though if your project is really big and your classes are tightly coupled. I would advice you to read [this article about Dependency Injection](http://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/dependency-injection/) and especially 'Dependency is bigger than Testing part' :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The class I want to use is kind of the "heart" in the application and has a lot of dependencies, and most of them I can't remove. It seems like we have to do some major refactoring of this class, I will have a look at how protocols could help us, not really sure how at the moment but worth some thoughts.